# Overleaf : undefined control sequence a \begin{document}

Tags: overleaf

The problem occurs because I use the package "minted" on Overleaf. Without it, the problems disappears (but I need the package).

So far I have tried the following, which does not seem to solve the issue :

- adding [cache=false] to the usepackage line
- using different compilers
- changing the language of the input file
- adding these two lines, as the overleaf document suggested

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
```

Here is the exact error message

```
\set@color ->\special {color push \current@color 
                                                 }\aftergroup \reset@color 
l.24 \begin{document}
                     
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Relevant to the question is that the file still compiles and looks like expectations. Although it would be nice not to have any errors.

Minimally reproducible example :

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

You can paste that into an overleaf document.

Comment: Can you make a [mre]?

Comment: Added minimal reproducible example

Comment: If I add the missing author and title, your code works fine on overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/read/xmhtpnxyhxzd